# How to download an image to a certain local folder using pure Javascript on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automation

I'm currently trying to download an image from a URL to a pre-defined local folder directory with pre-defined name. I'm quite new to JS so I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help?

The sample URL is: https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/06/14/5940ce00024f2.bmp Where the only content inside is a image.

I would like to download it to the default directory with name `test.jpg`

Is this possible?

I searched on the web and get a partial solution but this reqires mannually set directory and file name:

```
var $a = document.createElement('a');
$a.setAttribute("href","https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/06/14/5940ce00024f2.bmp");
$a.setAttribute("download", "");
var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evObj.initMouseEvent( 'click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, true, false, 0, null);
$a.dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

Thanks a lot~

Comment: Your web page can not tell me where to save a downloaded a file - it's called *security*

Comment: I didn't quite get your point about security, sorry...... I just want to automate this manual download process, not quite sure whether this is possible.

Comment: as I said, it's not possible due to security issues - if a rogue website was able to determine where a file is going to be saved, the potential harm is obvious

Comment: @JaromandaX So you mean the only thing I can do is to start a file download process, but exactly where to download and what name it takes can only be input by hand?

Comment: You can specify the name (I think you're on the right track for that), but not the location

Comment: @Wjx about security: if you could write to a specified path, why dont you write *explorer.exe* into *C:/Windows/System32/* ? ( just one of thousands of examples which can harm the user)

Comment: @JaromandaX but would it be possible to download it to the default directory?

Comment: @JaromandaX Also, the only goal is to save the image, so creating a new webpage or similar actions are all allowed~

Comment: This sounds like something you should do in a scripting language like python or node.js.

Comment: Yes. But not until the user approves the download

Comment: Is it possible to manually write a webpage with a download button and a link to the image and let JS open this new webpage and automatically download? Sometimes when I click the download button, Chrome directly download the content to file \Download.

Comment: Also, when I manually open this webpage, google chrome download it for me directly.

Comment: while sometimes, when the image is not displayed in the form ***.bmp, chrome refuse to download it automatically